# KnockoutJS toggle class on iterated list items

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have multiple viewmodels one called 'Music' the other one 'Tracks' as seen here below:

```
var Music = function (o, json) {
    var self            = this;
    self.localName      = ko.observable(json);
    self.thumbnail      = ko.observable();
    self.isSingle       = ko.observable(false);
    self.title          = ko.observable();
    self.year           = ko.observable();
    self.genre          = ko.observable();
    self.viewDetails    = ko.observable(false);
    self.tracks         = ko.observableArray();
    self.showAlbum  = function () {
        self.viewDetails(false);
        var album = self.localName();
        o.currentAlbum = album;

        if(self.isSingle() === true){
            _playSingle(o, album);
        } else {
            self.viewDetails(true);
            if(self.viewDetails(true) ){
                $(o.musicListSelector+' > li').hide();
            }

        }
    };
}

var Track = function (o, data) {
    var self            = this;
    self.name           = data;
    self.isActive       = ko.observable(false);
    self.playTrack      = function () {
        if(self.isActive(true)){
            self.isActive(false);
        }
        self.isActive(true);
        var trackname = self.name;
        _trackClickHandler(o, trackname);
    };
}
```

I'm having trouble toggeling the selected class of the current playing song in the list.
The class gets set properly, but once the next tracks starts, it also gets the class 'selected' but the class needs to be removed from the previous track.

I know I need to reference the parent to get this to work but somehow I can not wrap my brain around how to get this to work.

[image: example]

Because I use this code in my NodeJS project the HTML is Jade. I hope it makes sense:

```
    // ko if: music().length > 0
    ul.music(data-bind="foreach: music")
        li(data-bind="click: showAlbum , css : {'active' : viewDetails}")
            img.cover(data-bind="attr: { src: thumbnail }")
            .overlay
            a.title(data-bind="text:localName", style="visibility:hidden;")
            #albumInfo      
                h2(data-bind="text:title")
                // ko if: genre() !== 'Unknown' && genre() !== null
                .genre(data-bind="text:genre")
                // /ko
                // ko if: year() !== 'Unknown' && year() !== null
                .year(data-bind="text:year")
                // /ko
            #tracklist
                ul#tracks(data-bind="foreach: tracks")
                    li(data-bind="click: playTrack , css : {'selected' : isActive}")
                        i.play.icon
                        .title(data-bind="text:name")
    // /ko
```

I'd like to avoid DOM manipulation with for instance jQuery if possible.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not a jade expert but it looks like your not reseting the isactive flag for the track that was previously playing.

Suggest in your play track method you do the following:

1.) Set the currently active track isActive flag to false.

2.) Store the currently playing track to the one you just selected. On your viewModel

3.) Then set the isActive flag to true.

This should solve your problem I believe